# Spring Boot - nesting ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot comes with many cool features. My favourite one is a type-safe configuration mechanism through [`@ConfigurationProperties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) and corresponding yml/properties files. I'm writing a library that configures Cassandra connection via Datastax Java driver. I want to allow developers to configure `Cluster` and `Session` objects by simply editing yml file. This is easy in spring-boot. But I want to allow her/him configure multiple connections this way. In PHP framework - Symfony it is as easy as:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
      default:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
      customer:
        driver:   "%database_driver2%"
        host:     "%database_host2%"
        port:     "%database_port2%"
        dbname:   "%database_name2%"
        user:     "%database_user2%"
        password: "%database_password2%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

(this snippet comes from [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html))

Is it possible in spring-boot using ConfigurationProperties? Should I nest them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't type-safely nest arbitrary numbers of subobjects (such as your `connections`), although it's possible you might be able to declare a `Map<String,Connection> connections`. If that doesn't work, perhaps make a feature request on GitHub.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You could actually use type-safe nested `ConfigurationProperties`.

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class DatabaseProperties {

    private Connection primaryConnection;

    private Connection backupConnection;

    // getter, setter ...

    public static class Connection {

        private String host;

        // getter, setter ...

    }

}
```

Now you can set the property `primaryConnection.host`.

If you don't want to use inner classes then you can annotate the fields with `@NestedConfigurationProperty`.

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class DatabaseProperties {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Connection primaryConnection; // Connection is defined somewhere else

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Connection backupConnection;

    // getter, setter ...

}
```

See also the [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-nested-properties) and [Configuration Binding Docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding).

Comment: As of spring boot 1.3.0.RELEASE, the inner class needs to be public, otherwise I get 
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils can not access a member of class ...DatabaseProperties$Connection with modifiers "private"

Comment: How will be the getter and setter for regular class(non-inner class)?

Comment: These are regular getter and setter, just the same like in inner-classes. If you want to set the property `primaryConnection.host`, Spring invokes for you `getPrimaryConnection().setHost(value)` (very abstract and internally maybe not correct)

Comment: Why in Documentation nested class defined in PRIVATE? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-nested-properties

Comment: I defined my classes based on your syntax. How can these properties  from other class, since they are not visible from outside

Comment: Having defined the configuration as in the first example, I now need to inject two instances - one `DatabaseProperties dbProperties` and the second is `DatabaseProperties.Connection connectionProperties`, right? Doesn't look very convenient.

Comment: @Scadge you only need to inject `DatabaseProperties dbProperties`, from there you can call `dbProperties.getPrimaryConnection()` and `dbProperties.getBackupConnection()`

Comment: @RolandWeisleder I'm talking about the case when I need to retrieve the fields from the inner class, e.g. `host` in the current example

Comment: @Scadge inject `DatabaseProperties dbProperties` and call `dbProperties.getPrimaryConnection().getHost()`. If your property is `prefix.host` (without `primaryConnection`) then your class `Connection` must also be annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: You may use `lombok` @Data on both the outer & inner classes to have the setters and getters generated