# Using @ConfigurationProperties for nesting or direct access

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, lombok

I'd like to be able to access my "root" properties, or a subset. So I attempted to do this:

**RootProperties**

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@Data
@Validated
public class RootProperties
{
    @NotNull
    private SdkProperties sdk;
}
```

**SdkProperties**

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@Data
@Validated
public class SdkProperties
{
    @NotEmpty
    private String apiKey

    // ... etc.
}
```

So this way I can either autowire the full `RootProperties`, or just the `SdkProperties` class, depending on what I need to access for a given context.

However, when I have it configured this way, I get a stack overflow from Spring:

```
Cause: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2123.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.fieldvalues.javac.Tree.accept(Tree.java:44)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.fieldvalues.javac.JavaCompilerFieldValuesParser.getFieldValues(JavaCompilerFieldValuesParser.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.TypeElementMembers.process(TypeElementMembers.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.TypeElementMembers.<init>(TypeElementMembers.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processTypeElement(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedType(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.lambda$processNestedLombokTypes$3(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:364)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedLombokTypes(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processTypeElement(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:279)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedType(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:423)

    ...

    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedType(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.lambda$processNestedLombokTypes$3(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:364)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedLombokTypes(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processTypeElement(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:279)

    ( ... hundreds more of these blocks ... )
```

How can I support this workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@NestedConfigurationProperty`

I think old post answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/29588215/8308536

Comment: Cool, thanks! Maybe you can help with this one, too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58435628/validate-fields-only-of-other-field-is-false