# Validate fields only if other field is false

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, configuration, lombok

Suppose I have an `@ConfigurationProperties` class which needs to validate a set of fields based on the value of another field. For example, `SdkProperties` has an `enabled` field. Only when `enabled` is `true` should the other fields be validated.

**SdkProperties**

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(...)
@Data
@Validated
public class SdkProperties
{
    private boolean enabled;

    @NotEmpty
    private String apiKey

    // ... etc.
}
```

The `@NotEmpty` annotation should only be validated if `enabled` is `true`.

What's the proper way to do this?

I have seen examples of using `@AssertTrue` and an `isValid` function to handle the validation by hand. But I don't want to do that.

I wonder if this is doable using validation groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom `ConstraintValidator`.

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sdk")
@Validated
@NotEmptyWhenEnabled // <----- custom validation -----
@Data
class SdkProperties {

    private boolean enabled;
    private String apiKey;
}

@Constraint(validatedBy = {NotEmptyWhenEnabledValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface NotEmptyWhenEnabled {
    String message() default "SDK apiKey needed when SDK is enabled";

    Class[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

class NotEmptyWhenEnabledValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotEmptyWhenEnabled,SdkProperties> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(SdkProperties sdkProperties, 
                           ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        boolean enabled = sdkProperties.isEnabled();
        boolean empty = null == sdkProperties.getApiKey() || sdkProperties.getApiKey().isEmpty();
        return !enabled || (enabled && !empty);
    }
}
```

Then you get a nice message on startup when *SDK is enabled* but the *API-key is not* provided.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'sdk' to so.demo.SdkProperties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1ecd6003 failed:

    Reason: SDK apiKey needed when SDK is enabled


Action:

Update your application's configuration


Process finished with exit code 0
```

***EDIT***

Since `spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE` (16 Oct 2019) you have another option.
You could validate the properties in the constructor.

by using: **Immutable @ConfigurationProperties** binding

> Configuration properties now support constructor-based binding, which allows a `@ConfigurationProperties`-annotated class to be immutable. Constructor-based binding can be enabled by annotating a `@ConfigurationProperties` class or one of its constructors with `@ConstructorBinding`. Annotations such as `@DefaultValue` and `@DateTimeFormat` can be used on constructor parameters that are provided by configuration property binding.

ref: [boot-features-external-config-constructor-binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-constructor-binding)

so in your case...

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sdk")
class SdkProperties {

    private boolean enabled;
    private String apiKey;

    @ConstructorBinding
    public SdkProperties(boolean enabled, String apiKey) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        // direct validation in the constructor
        boolean apiKeyNullOrEmpty = null == apiKey || apiKey.isEmpty();
        Assert.isTrue(!enabled || !apiKeyNullOrEmpty, "When SDK is enabled, a SDK-api key is mandatory!");
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {  return enabled; }
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) { this.enabled = enabled; }
    public String getApiKey() {return apiKey; }
    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) { this.apiKey = apiKey; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: This probably would have worked but I ended up just adding some `@AssertTrue isValid` methods to handle this as I thought this solution was overkill for my needs. Thanks though!

Comment: @JoshM. improved answer. Maybe too late for you, but could be useful for others.